# Dependency Injection Constructor Conflict

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a controller and I want to use Dependency Injection with constructor,this is my code

```
    private readonly IHomeService _iHomeService;

    public HomeController(IHomeService iHomeService)
    {
        _iHomeService = iHomeService;
    }

    public HomeController()
    {

    }
```

When I remove Constructor without any parameter(Second Constructor),I see this error :

```
No parameterless constructor defined
```

and When I use Constructor without any parameter,I see my private field is null(_iHomeService = null) because program use constructor without parameter.

How can I resolve this problem for Dependency Injection?

Comment: Are you using an IoC container like Castle Windsor?

Comment: No I do not use any Ioc container

Answer (score 1):

Well, to do dependency injection youll need to either use a framework or use controller factory .

try [ninject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Dependency-injection-for-controllers)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWelcomeMessageService welcomeMessageService;

    public HomeController(IWelcomeMessageService welcomeMessageService)
    {
        this.welcomeMessageService = welcomeMessageService;
    }

    public void Index()
    {
        ViewModel.Message = this.welcomeMessageService.TodaysWelcomeMessage;
        return View();
    }
}

public class WelcomeMessageServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<IWelcomeMessageService>().To<WelcomeMessageService>();
    }
}
```

The framework will take control on the controller instance creation and pass the constractor params

Comment: You don't actually need a framework to do DI, it's perfectly possible to inject dependencies manually.

Comment: @JoeR - I already corrected that "youll need to either(!) use a framework or(!) use controller factory ."

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET uses a `ControllerFactory` to instantiate your controllers on-demand. This class requires that your controller has a parameterless constructor that it can use to create an instance of it.

You'll need to use a dependency injection framework to create your controllers and inject the required dependencies. [ASP.NET has some dependency injection capability](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/dependency-injection), but I understand that it is flawed. I suggest using [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) to manage your dependency injection. It integrates very well with ASP.NET, and there's a tutorial on integrating it [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-one-getting-Windsor.ashx).

If you go down this route, you'd end up with an installer for your controllers and service:

```
public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<IHomeService>.ImplementedBy<HomeService>());
    }
}
```

..and a new `ControllerFactory` to create them:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        _kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
        }
        return (IController) _kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```

Finally, you'd create a container and set a new controller factory:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new Installer());
var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(_container.Kernel);
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
```

You could also use [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) or [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are expecting, automatically, the `HomeService` class to be instantiated and injected into the Controller.

Using an IoC framework like Ninject or StructureMap will do that for you - once you've set it up.

If you don't want to use an IoC framework, you'll need to manually instantiate the `HomeService` in your constructor.